# How to download .apk and .ipa file programatically from fabric or Jenkins?

Tags: java, android, ios, jenkins, automation

We get the build through Fabric which gets it from Jenkins CI.
To rephrase, we generate the new app build for both iOS and Android through Jenkins and configured it to publish it to Fabric.

I want to fetch that .ipa and .app file , download it and install it directly on the device programatically either from Jenkins or Fabric. I'm using a java framework build around Appium for test automation.

Comment: is the problem the downloading or the installing? if both, you probably want different questions for each. do you know the URLs such that you could download an .ipa, for example, outside of jenkins? if so, use `curl` or `wget` or the java or ruby equivalents for download?

Answer (score 1):

Well this is something I read some time back and I can't remember the person who answered this. But you can thank the unknown person for this.

For an iOS build in fabric, you can open the page into Safari browser and then enable the following, **Settings > Safari > Advanced > Web Console**

The button action looks something like this

```
<a class="primary-button js-install-button" href="itms-service xxxx ">Download</a>
```

So here you have the download URL which is encoded. You can easily decode this by some php command

```
php -r "echo urldecode('{ABOVE URL}');"
```

This will actually give the xml manifest file where actual download link for ipa is present. This link is the way to download the actual file.